# paperclip to show image/document link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use paperclip and want to display document link in show page. I am using

```
 <%= image_tag @event.photo.url(:small) %>
```

Problem is that it will not display link. also for image I only want to show link not thumbnail.How can it possible??
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is simply:

```
<%= @event.photo.url(:small) %>
```

`image_tag` is a helper creating the proper html tags to display the picture.

```
<%= link_to "pic name here", @event.photo.url(:small) %>
```

Comment: thanks apneadiving for quick responce.it works but i want to show it as a link so that on click it will display original photo/document

Answer (score 3):

If you want get original photo by click on link do:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@event.photo.url(:small)), @event.photo.url(:original) %>
```